# Mypy: cast tuple values

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

```
def my_function(key, parameters: tuple[int | str, ...] | tuple[MyClass, ...]) -> None
    if key == "id":
        parameters = tuple(map(int, parameters))
```

The last line raises

```
Argument 1 to "map" has incompatible type "Type[int]"; expected "Callable[[Union[MyClass, int, str]], int]"mypy(error)
```

How do I make this work? How do I tell mypy that I know that my tuple is made of int and str but not MyClass?

Comment: `my_function` may be better off being split into two separate functions that each don't have to examine the value of `key` to determine what to do with `parameters`.

Comment: "How do I tell mypy that I know that my tuple is made of int and str *but not MyClass*?" Why would that be the case? The annotation for ``parameters`` clearly states there could be ``MyClass`` instances in the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typing.cast` to assert that `parameters` has type `tuple[int|str,...]`:

```
parameters = tuple(map(int, typing.cast(tuple[int|str,...], parameters)))
```

You might also consider using `typing.overload` to separate the signature into two simpler signatures.

```
from typing import overload, Literal

@overload
def my_function(key, parameters: tuple[int|str, ...]) ->  None:
    ...

@overload
def my_function(key, parameters: tuple[MyClass,...]) -> None:
    ...


def my_function(key, parameters):
    if key == "id":
       parameters = tuple(map(int, parameters))
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I do this and then try to call the function, for example like `my_function("name", list_of_strings)` I get `No overload variant of "my_function" matches argument types "str", "Tuple[str, ...]"`

Comment: Then you should probably add a third overloaded signature. Those strings don't sound like something you can apply `int` to, and there's not enough detail in your actual implementation to let us know every way you might call `my_function`.

Comment: Union types are often a sign that your one function is trying to do too many different things.